# Bash generate multiple files with data from other file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm completely new to scripting and linux.
I will like to make a script which will generate Z numbers (1 - 10.000) of .txt files with data from another file.

Example of generated files wanted:

> file1.txt

```
Number: X
Date: 31.07.2017<br>
Text: test
```

> file2.txt

```
Number: Y
Date: 31.07.2017
Text: test
```

file3.txt..

file4125.txt.

file10000.txt

Where **X**, **Y** are replaced with a number from file numbers.txt which have one number per line. Each new file must have a unique "Number" from numbers.txt file.
And in the end move all the files to a new location e.g. `/home/razvan/files`.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you share here what you have already tried and point out the particular problems you have with that code, you are much more likely to get help quickly. Please also have a look [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what's in the numbers.txt file?

Comment: @RamanSailopal a list of random numbers: 24215, 125415, 15215, 1245, 62432, 8235, 1, 654, 96543. But each number on a separate line.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
count=0
while read -r number; do
    count=$(( count + 1 ))
    printf 'Number: %s
Date: 31.07.2017
Text: test' "$number" >"/home/razvan/file$count.txt"
done < numbers.txt
```

Loop through all the lines in `numbers.txt` and create a file for each one, using `printf` to create the formatted string containing `$number`.

This will create a list of files starting with `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, etc. inside the directory `/home/razvan`.

Answer (score 0):

numbafile:

```
78
67
77

 awk '{ print "Number: "$0"\nDate: 31.07.2017\nText: test" > ("/home/razvan/numbafile"$0".txt") }' numbafile
```

With gawk, use the number in each line of the numbafile and then use this ($0) to print data to a file (named with $0) i.e. /home/razvan/numbafile78.txt